# How to pass multiple authorization keys to swagger-js?

Tags: javascript, swagger-ui

Using [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) version 2.1.0 I'm trying to pass multiple authorization params to the URL requested. Looking at the [example given on github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#header-parameters) I've tried:

```
var api_key = 'api_key',
    username = 'username';

swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add('api_key', new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('api_key', api_key, 'query'));
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add('username', new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('username', username, 'query'));
```

But this results in only the first one of them being passed to the XHR, e.g.:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/capability?api_key=api_key

If I swap the order:

```
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add('username', new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('username', username, 'query'));
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add('api_key', new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('api_key', api_key, 'query'));
```

Then:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/channel?username=username

I've also tried using the object notation in add:

```
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add({
    'api_key': new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", api_key, "query"),
    'username': new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("username", username, "query")
});
```

But again only single parameter was passed:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/capability?api_key=api_key

The name of the function suggests it should be possible to pass multiple authorization params without any collisions but the practice shows otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that seems to work for me is to bind a custom function to `swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.apply`, e.g.:

```
    swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.apply = function (obj) {
        obj.url += '?api_key=' + api_key + '&username=' + username;
    }
```

(the example assumes that api_key and username are present in the current scope)

[`swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.apply`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/master/dist/swagger-ui.js) takes two arguments `obj, securities` - it's the first one you'll want to use to attach credentials to your HTTP requests.